# 2-column layout without table

Tags: css, html

Here's a variation on the "2 column layout without tables" question that I can't figure out.  It is really common to build web pages that have a combination of headings, labels and data.  For example:

```
User info
-----------------------------
Name:      John Doe
Address:   1234 Main St.
           Anytown, CT

Contact info
-----------------------------

Email:     johndoe@gmail.com
Phone:     (324)555-1234
```

It's easy enough to use the CSS `display: table`, `display: table-row`, and `display: table-cell` styles to lay out the labels and associated data values.  But how do I deal with the heading rows ("User info" and "Contact info"), which need to span multiple columns?

Comment: What browsers do you need to support?  Also, this arguably is tabular information.  If you just need someone's permission to use tables and not feel guilty, I'm happy to oblige. Go ahead and do it.  No one is looking.

Comment: Use `<td rowspan="2">User info</td>`?  Why not use tables?  Why does everyone hate tables?  What did they ever do?

Comment: I totally agree, it is that tables are designed just for these kind of cases, to show tabular information. It is so wrong to use any kind of other element here!